# Temperature vs electric conductivity in a solid

Tags: solid-state-physics, temperature, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics

Generally with increase in temperature the chemical potential is reduced which would mean at lower temperatures the electric conductivity should become higher.

But for semiconductors if we lower temperature the electrical conductivity becomes lower.Why?

Comment: Carrier concentration. Metals have a reduction from increasing scattering with increasing temperature. Reconsider your generalization…

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would would suggest you read the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/467901/what-is-energy-band-gap).

When you look at the allowed energy levels of a semiconductor, there are certain energies that no electrons will have; this occurs due to the density of states (often $g(E)$) of electrons in that material. The carrier concentration is a product, $g(E) f_D(E)$, number of energy states available times the probability of occupation; $f_D(E)$ is the Fermi Dirac distribution. $f_D(E)$ is actually dependent on temperature,

$$
f_D(E) = \frac{1}{e^{(E-E_f)/k T}+1}
$$

where $E_f$ is the Fermi energy (or the chemical potential). It is true that $E_f$ does decrease with increased temperature, but it normally is not significant (on the order of $10^{-1}-10^{-2}$eV, while the values of interest of $f_D$ are normally larger).

The shift in the chemical potential can be understood a bit more by looking at the density of states for a system with a fixed number of electrons. Assume a free electron gas; let's look at some energy value just above the $E_f$. The density of states generally increases with energy, so there are fewer states just below $E_f$ than just above. As temperature increases, $f_D$ "spreads" symmetrically around $E_f$; but because $g(E)$ is not symmetric, the integral of the new concentration would suggest that we now have more total electrons than there were initially. So that this does not happen, $E_f$ must decrease.

Qualitatively, this is what happens (assuming a simple density of state):

at low temperatures, there are few electrons excited into the conduction band (CB)
[image: low temp concentration]

at higher temperatures, there are more excited electrons
[image: high temp conc]

It really comes down to the fact that the Fermi energy lies in the gap (often on the order of 2eV), while the shift is so much smaller.